# How to do classification in binary data set using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

I have the following binary dataset:

```
[
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
]
```

I want to cluster(scatter) this into 3 parts in such a way that the arrays with most similarity(0s and 1s at the same position in array) are clustered in same group.

Since I have learned that binary data cannot be clustered straight away and need the dimensions to be reduced. The [manifold learning algorithms](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html) are capable of doing that. I am trying to reduce it to as little as 2 dimensions and then scatter it on a plot to make it more user friendly, Multi-dimensional scaling seems to be the [most promising algorithm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html#multi-dimensional-scaling-mds) for doing this. But when I fit it around my dataset, it still returns the same dataset without any reductions:

```
mds = MDS(n_components=2, metric=True, n_init=4, max_iter=300, verbose=0, eps=0.001, n_jobs=1, random_state=None, dissimilarity='euclidean')
mds.fit(X)
return X
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong or what am I missing? I am trying to reduce this data set to 2 dimensions and then cluster it on a 2d scatter graph such that the the arrays which are similar are grouped together and closely based on the similarity in positions of 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 0):

`fit()` only learns the data and not changes it in any way. You need to call `fit_transform()` to get new transformed data. Like this:

```
newX = mds.fit_transform(X)
```

`newX` will be the data with 2 components as you wanted.